# bigbluebutton installation issue

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, bigbluebutton

i am trying to install bigbluebutton.
i am following installation procedure from this link 
http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html

if you visit this above mention link
on the installation section you will find this

```
$ sudo bbb-conf --status
red5 ——————————————————► [✔ - active]
nginx —————————————————► [✔ - active]
freeswitch ————————————► [✔ - active]
redis-server ——————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-apps-akka —————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-transcode-akka ————► [✔ - active]
bbb-fsesl-akka ————————► [✔ - active]
tomcat7 ———————————————► [✔ - active]
mongod ————————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-html5 —————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-webrtc-sfu ————————► [✔ - active]
kurento-media-server ——► [✔ - active]
etherpad ——————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-web ———————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-lti ———————————————► [✔ - active]

when i did it on my ubuntu 16.04
i get this

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# sudo bbb-conf --status
nginx —————————————————► [✔ - active]
freeswitch ————————————► [✔ - active]
redis-server ——————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-apps-akka —————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-transcode-akka ————► [✔ - active]
bbb-fsesl-akka ————————► [✔ - active]
red5 ——————————————————► [✔ - active]
tomcat7 ———————————————► [✔ - active]
mongod ————————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-html5 —————————————► [✔ - active]
bbb-webrtc-sfu ————————► [✘ - failed]
kurento-media-server ——► [✔ - active]
etherpad ——————————————► [✘ - failed]
bbb-web ———————————————► [✔ - active]
```

means at my side bbb-web-rtc-sfu and etherpad are failed.please let me know why they are failed and how can i fix this issue so that i can successfully run bigbluebutton on my ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you check => https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/troubleshooting

Comment: yes i check it but i could not find any solution. can you please mention any section of this link.

Comment: i am rechecking the troubleshoot portion mention in the link provided by you @Jac

Comment: @Jac i didnt find any thing still the same.could you tell me why these 2 services were fail to start.

Comment: Let's try to understand where is the problem. Did you try...```bbb-conf --debug``` ?

Comment: You simply need to analyze logs properly to understand which is the root problem. bbb-conf has few parameters that prints errors, like "--clean --debug" or "--check"

Answer (score 0):

First Add bigbluebutton/support Repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigbluebutton/support
```

Then install bbb-webrtc-sfu

```
sudo apt-get install bbb-webrtc-sfu
```

After that please check etherpad is stop Or Not

```
systemctl check etherpad
```